# Как написать запрос для вывода суммы покупок, сгруппированных по дате

Tags: mysql, запрос, datetime, group-by

Написать MySQL запрос который выведет на какую сумму было продано игр ежемесячно в течение одного года по данной снизу таблице(данных не много конечно но приблизительно). Сам я не очень понимаю как это правильно сделать.

[image: purchase table]

Answer (score 0):

Допустим так:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, '%c.%Y'), sum(summary_cost) 
from table_salary
group by DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, '%c.%Y');
```